# Sending emails - MFMailComposeResult

Tags: switch-statement, swift

I'm trying to migrate one of my applications from Obj-C to Swift and I've a problem with the emails management.
I searched by hours but I did not found how solve this problem.
Basically, I'm trying to migrate the `func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!)` function.

The problem is that no options, inside the switch, are valid.

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!)
{
    switch result.value
    {
        case CUnsignedInt(MFMailComposeResultCancelled):
            var alert = UIAlertController(
                title: NSLocalizedString("sendingStatus", tableName: "LocalizationFile", comment:"sendingStatus"),
                message: NSLocalizedString("emailCancelledByUser", tableName: "LocalizationFile", comment:"emailCancelledByUser"),
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case MFMailComposeResult(MFMailComposeResultFailed):
            var alert = UIAlertController(
                title: NSLocalizedString("sendingStatus", tableName: "LocalizationFile", comment:"sendingStatus"),
                message: NSLocalizedString("emailSentFailed", tableName: "LocalizationFile", comment:"emailSentFailed"),
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            var alert = UIAlertController(
                title: NSLocalizedString("sendingStatus", tableName: "LocalizationFile", comment:"sendingStatus"),
                message: NSLocalizedString("emailSaved", tableName: "LocalizationFile", comment:"emailSaved"),
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        default:
            var alert = UIAlertController(
                title: NSLocalizedString("sendingStatus", tableName: "LocalizationFile", comment:"sendingStatus"),
                message: NSLocalizedString("emailNotSent", tableName: "LocalizationFile", comment:"emailNotSent"),
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't forget that you can also use `.rawValue` (`.value` in older versions of Swift) on the specific result types you're comparing your variable result to:

```
    var result:MFMailComposeResult = MFMailComposeResultCancelled

    switch(result.value) { // <-- Here, note .value is being used
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value: // <-- And here as well!
            print("Cancelled")
        default:
            print("Default")
    }
```

Comment: OMG! Really works fine... I don't know how I not saw this. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: You now use .rawValue instead of .value

Comment: Works without .rawValue in Swift version 2.2, not sure what version fixed that

Answer (score 3):

**Tested and works 100%**
In swift 3.0 this is changed and now you should make something like this:

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                           didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResult.Cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResult.Saved.rawValue:
        print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResult.Sent.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResult.Failed.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent failure: %@", [error!.localizedDescription])
    default:
        break
    }
    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the 100% tested in swift 3 was only about 50% tested. When I tried it the compiler did not really like it. XCode help me fix it though to one that did work as of 9-1-17. The code that follows is the code that did finally compile:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?){
    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResult.saved.rawValue:
        print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
        print("Mail sent failure: %@", [error!.localizedDescription])
    default:
        break
    }
    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```